# How do I allow just 1 user to push to a branch in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

[image]

I would like for only 1 user to be able to push (force push and regular push) to a certain branch, and everyone else to not have permissions to push.

These are the permissions I set (with my user listed under "Restrict who can push to matching branches". However, when I try to force push I get a branch protected error.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot differentiate users on a branch level. However, if you have continuous integration, you can make this branch pull request only and let the CI build system check who are making the changes and allow merges on per your whitelist.

Comment: right that's the idea (to allow my CI user to merge and nobody else). But how do I give my CI user the permissions to do the merge

Comment: I think commonly you will require one of the CI checks (in your case, whitelist check in the second checkbox in the screenshot you posted) to pass before anything can be merged. If that check does not pass, no one can merge it. If that passes, meaning the person's change is allowed to go in, then you can either let some user merge it or make a minimal GitHub app to automatically merge it. @Toli does that make sense?

Comment: ah I think I understand

Answer (score 2):

> Actually, that still doesn't allow the user to force push.

[Since Dec. 4th 2019](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-12-04-expanded-branch-protection-rules/), there is a way to grant all users with push access the ability to force-push to a protected branch by enabling `Allow force pushes`.

If the CI user has push access to (the protected branch) `master`, it will be able to force push.

Answer (score -1):

First, you will want to make the branch pull request only. The screenshot you showed will get you that.

After that is done, I guess you can make one of the CI checks to be "checking if the author of the pull request is in the whitelist".

Then, in the "require status check to pass before merging", add the check mentioned in the last step.

Now, no one can ever make changes to this branch unless your CI says "yes, this author is allowed to make changes in this branch"

As for if you want to automatically merge branches that pass the whitelist check, I will not suggest doing it, but if you want to, there are many GitHub apps that can do that, and you can also make a very minimal GitHub app yourself using the GitHub APIs.

Comment: actually that still doesn't allow the user to force push. Basically here is our setup:

- master (only mergable via PR)
- once every week master is automatically force pushed to staging by the CI user. Only the CI user should be able to do this

Comment: @Toli does the CI user force push to master, or push whatever is in master to a staging branch? Either way, I think it will work as long as it is PR based, it is just a matter of which branch you put the rules on. However, if it is not PR based, but a force push, I don't think there is any good way of doing it other than making the CI user an administrator, but not sure if anyone wants to do that.

Comment: @Toli can you describe how, do you think, a user can bypass and pour changes under the policy I described?